# Sorting np.array of dates

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, date, datetime

I'm having this matrix of dates that I would like to sort by dates and then have back in the same format as it started

```
data = np.array(
    [[2015, 1, 1, 23, 4, 59],
     [2015, 4, 30, 23, 5, 1],
     [2015, 1, 1, 23, 5, 25],
     [2015, 2, 15, 58,5, 0],
     [2015, 5, 20, 50, 27, 37],
     [2015, 6, 21, 25, 27, 29]])
```

I tried datetime.datetime, but couldn't convert the data back to this format

Comment: Could you please post example data + code you tried as text instead of image? That would be very helpful; less guessing, better answers.

Comment: @FObersteiner of course sorry..

tvec_tom = np.zeros((0,6))
    tvec_a = np.empty((24,6))
    if period == "hour":
        data_a = np.zeros((24,4))
        t=np.ones(24,dtype=bool)
        for n in range(24):
            for i in range(len(data)):
                if tvec[i,3] == n:
                    data_a[n,:] += data[i,:]
                    tvec_tom = np.vstack([tvec_tom,tvec[i,:]])
            tvec_tom = tvec_tom.astype(int)
            date_list = [datetime.datetime(*x) for x in tvec_tom]
        print(date_list)

Comment: And this could be an example of data

2006,9,11,0,0,0, 5.0, 6.0, 1.0, 8.0
2006,4,21,8,2,0, 3.0,1.0,-1.0, 6.0
2006,7,14,9,0,59, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0
2006,9,31,2,3,0, 7.0,-1.0, 9.0, 0.0

Comment: can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74595193/edit) your question to include those details there? That would be more readable than in the comments section ;-)

Comment: @FObersteiner I tried to make the question a bit more precise this time, with code and data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort your data without the conversion to datetime, since the date/time components already appear in sorted order (year, month, etc.). So a `np.sort(data, axis=0)` should do:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array(
    [[2015, 1, 1, 23, 4, 59],
      [2015, 4, 30, 23, 5, 1],
      [2015, 1, 1, 23, 5, 25],
      [2015, 2, 15, 58,5, 0],
      [2015, 5, 20, 50, 27, 37],
      [2015, 6, 21, 25, 27, 29]])

np.sort(data, axis=0)
array([[2015,    1,    1,   23,    4,    0],
        [2015,    1,    1,   23,    5,    1],
        [2015,    2,   15,   23,    5,   25],
        [2015,    4,   20,   25,    5,   29],
        [2015,    5,   21,   50,   27,   37],
        [2015,    6,   30,   58,   27,   59]])
```